# How to get a multi part object from openstack swift using jclouds

Tags: java, openstack, openstack-swift, jclouds

I am trying to store and retrieve binary objects from swift using jclouds.openstack.swift API

Question: How to download objects using ranges.

For example:

```
          swiftApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
              .endpoint("....")
              .credentials(identity, credentials)
              .modules(modules)
              .buildApi(SwiftApi.class);

    final ObjectApi objectApi = 
               swiftApi.objectApiInRegionForContainer(REGION, CONTAINER);

    GetOptions getOptions = 
                     GetOptions.Builder.range(0,10).range(100, 200);

    SwiftObject obj = objectApi.get(OBJECT_NAME, getOptions);
            Payload payload = obj.getPayload();
            // ????? I expected a binary stream but i get something else
            payload2.openStream()
```

When i dump the stream as string i see headers and mime parts arriving but i don't understand how to access the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jclouds 1.7.2 does not support this and I reported [JCLOUDS-575](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-575) to track this issue.